# How to find out which data sets destroy my data analysis using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, analytics, cluster-analysis

I have 200 samples, each of them has 60 features. I use PCA to find the principal components. I use neural network and also try k nearest neighbor  However, the classification results are not good. I don't mind to take out some samples, but how I can tell which samples destroy my classification results? I know I can try them one by one, but it would be very ineffective. Please help

Comment: You could start by chucking out outliers, maybe anything that is more than 2 or 3 standard deviations from the mean. It depends on your data though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of throwing out some samples you need to throw out some attributes.

PCA computes a matrix with d x d entries. At 60 attributes, this matrix has 3600 entries. You have only 200 samples to compute the contents of this matrix - no wonder that the result is pretty much random. You need fewer variables and more data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical machine learning problem. There is always a risk with such a high number of features (in your case 60) with only 200 samples. Please check whether you have features which are redundant. Let me give an example

Imagine, we have to predict housing prices from the following features
1. Size in m2
2. Number of bedrooms
3. House age
4. Size in foot2

Please note that here number 2 and number 4 features both gives the same information and they are redundant. At first it does not look that disturbing. But if you have data like that its better to remove those features.

Therefore, i would recommend you to look first in your features and then into data. For more details you have a look in Machine Learning class(by Prof. Ng) from Stanford available in coursera